# TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' in Python program

Tags: python, anaconda, junit-jupiter

Here is my code:

```
dic = test_dataset.class_indices
idc = {k:v for v, k in dic.items()}

img = load_img( r'C:\Users\sreep\Downloads\Alzheimer_s Dataset\test\NonDemented\26 (62).jpg', target_size = (224,224,3))
img = img_to_array(img)
img = img/255
imshow(img)
plt.axis('off')
img = np.expand_dims(img,axis=0)
answer = model.predict(img)
probability = round(np.max(model.predict(img)*100),2)

print(probability, '% chances are there that the image is',idc[answer[0]])
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17688/2364562646.py in <module>
     13 probability = round(np.max(model.predict(img)*100),2)
     14 
---> 15 print(probability, '% chances are there that the image is',idc[answer[0]])

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Comment: Can you share a minimal working example.  We can't run your code when we don't have access to things stored on your computer.

Comment: Have a look [at similar cases on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=TypeError%3A+unhashable+type%3A+%27numpy.ndarray%27).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
 idc[np.argmax(answer[0])]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`answer[0]` is a numpy array and you are trying to use it as a key to the dictionary `idc`. Dictionary keys should be hashable, hence the error. Also please provide an example next time so other people can replicate your problem.